# Revoke API Key / Keystore in Envoy

Tags: jwt, authorization, envoyproxy

Our APIs are secured through the use of JWT long lived tokens (that act as API keys). We're planning to use Envoy authn filter to secure our endpoints. However, since the tokens are long lived we'd need a mean to validate that the token had not been revoked. I looked at the documentation in search for a kind of key store, to either store valid tokens or blacklisted tokens. So far I did not find anything relevant.

Is there a way to perform this out-of-the-box in envoy ?
Having short lived tokens are not an option for us right now.

Thanks